# Unable to add existing python installation as the python interpeter of a Pycharm project

Tags: pycharm

Let's get started on connecting up an existing interpreter:

[image]

An existing interpreter was selected:

[image]

But after hitting OK and going back to opening dialog our selection has *disappeared*:

[image]

I have tried this a half dozen times now: no joy.  I am on `Pycharm Pro 2022.3.1`